# Noise of Public Key Ciphertexts in HElib

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, implementation, key-generation

I would like to get a feeling on how the noise develops in different FHE schemes. So I ran some experiments using HElib for both BGV and CKKS. I wanted to look at the noise of a fresh public key and a fresh secret key ciphertext in both schemes. Curiously, in both schemes the noise I obtained was the same for public key and secret key ciphertexts. This should not be the case, the noise of a public key ciphertext should be much bigger than that of a secret key ciphertext.
I had used the code to generate the context and the keys from the BGV/CKKS examples in the HElib Git. When I looked more closely, I found the following lines.

```
helib::SecKey secret_key(context);
secret_key.GenSecKey();

// Public key management.
// Set the secret key (upcast: SecKey is a subclass of PubKey).
const helib::PubKey& public_key = secret_key;
```

My question therefore is: does this mean the examples on the HElib Git run both BGV and CKKS as secret key schemes, by setting the public key to be the secret key? This would explain the results I got in my noise experiments. Then my follow up question would be, how is it possible to generate a "true" public key in HElib? All code examples that I found when searching instantiate the public key as the secret key and there is no function `GenPubKey()` or the like in HElib.

On the other hand in `SecKey::GenSecKey()` it seems that the public key is generated alongside the secret key. So maybe I am misreading these code lines. Then my question would be whether you have some ideas why the noise of a secret key ciphertext is the same as the noise of a public key ciphertext in HElib?